# (#200) Permissions error facebook

Tags: facebook

Estou tentando desenvolver uma aplicação que faça uma busca de conteudo no facebook, exemplo eu tenho uma lista de palavras chaves, e com estas eu faço a busca e o facebook irá retornar o conteudo na forma de **JSON** de onde estiver publicado e é claro a visibilidade de cada postagem tem estar publica para ser coletado, porém quando tento executar no browser a url abaixo não funciona, segue:

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=comida&type=post

### Erro:

```
  {
     "error": {
     "message": "(#200) Permissions error",
     "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 200
    }
  }
```

quando tento passar o access token ocorre outro erro:
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/search?type=post&q=comida&access_token=[token]

### Erro

```
 {
  "error": {
   "message": "(#11) Post search has been deprecated",
   "type": "OAuthException",
   "code": 11
  }
 }
```

Alguem já passou por isso?
Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acho o primeiro erro irrelevante, pois para usar a API é obrigatório usar o TOKEN, então irei falar sobre o segundo erro.

### (#11) Post search has been deprecated

Conforme esta resposta do [SO-en](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23492541/1518921)

A versão 2.0 do GraphAPI não permite que você busque mensagens. Veja a [documentação atualizada](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.0#search).

Você pode continuar a buscar por postagens se você mudar a chamada da API para:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v1.0/search?q=search_query&type=post&access_token={access_token}
```

O exemplo adiciona `v1.0/` após `https://graph.facebook.com/`

Porém conforme este comentário

A versão v1.0 não irá mais funcionar após [30/Abril/2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23491308/facebook-api-post-search-deprecated#comment39306042_23492541).

Em outras palavras, tal ferramenta não será mais disponível.

Leia sobre o upgrade: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading

### Endpoints já não disponíveis em v2.0

- `/me/locations`foi removido. Use `/me/tagged_places`.
- `/me/checkins` foi removido, juntamente com a permissão do `user_checkins`.
- `/me/questions` foi removido, juntamente com a permissão do `user_questions`. Inclue também `/{page-id}/questions`, `/{group-id}/questions`, `/{question-id}` e `/{question-option-id}`.
- `/me/subscribers` e `/me/subscribedto` foram removidos.
- `/me/username` não mais disponivel.
- `/me/notes` não mais disponivel, juntamente com a permissão do `user_notes`.
- `/{page-id}/notes` não mais disponivel.
- `/{page-id}/questions` não mais disponivel.
- `Public Post search` não mais disponivel. (`/search?type=post&q=foobar`)
- `News Feed search` não mais disponivel (`/me/home?q=foobar`)
- `Start Now` não mais disponivel.

Comment: obrigado era exatamento isso que eu queria saber